# Join Free Space on 2 Different drives (EEEPC with 2 SSDs)

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, join

I have an **EEE PC 901** that has **2 SSD** drives **4 GB and 8GB**.

I Installed "***Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx***", and I'm very happy with it.

My only problem is that If I go to my ***home/*** or ***"File System"***  I only have 168MB, but if I go to ***"16 GB File System"*** (mounted in /media/) I have **8.4 GB**.

My question is, Is it possible to **join** (something like **unpartitioning**, if that's even a word) the 2 disks?

Or is it possible to put some parts of linux on one disk and others on the other?

Additional Info:
Result from "***>df -h***"

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             3.5G  2.8G  606M  83% /
none                  493M  272K  493M   1% /dev
none                  497M 1000K  496M   1% /dev/shm
none                  497M   88K  497M   1% /var/run
none                  497M     0  497M   0% /var/lock
none                  497M     0  497M   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sdb1              15G  5.7G  8.4G  41% /media/9c9235be-7475-4448-9b05-b9222dce7660
```

Comment: You can either use them cleverly as P_M said or use a file system like XFS on both which creates a clever RAID out of them which appears like a huge drive.

Comment: Do you know if gparted is up for the job? (of changing my filesystem without needing to reformat?)

Comment: I do not think this can be done without erasing everything and changing it to XFS or btrfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the Ubuntu installation you can choose to do manual partitioning, and then you can tell it to put /home on a different disk/partition immediately.

If you want to do it after installing, you can move everything in `/home` on `sda1` (including hidden files!) to the root of the 8 (or 16?) GB disk `sdb1`, and then add something like the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1        /home           ext4    relatime        0       2
```

(Of course if you formatted the second SSD as another type of filesystem, make sure you replace 'ext4' by the right one!)

Moving those files is best done from a live CD/USB because moving them while running the system is probably not going to be liked by some applications...  But make sure you change fstab on the first SSD and not on the system running from the USB stick (or CD) then!

---

BTW: "joining" multiple physical disks to 1 virtual disk can be done with LVM, but that's probably more complicated than you want right now...  (And RAID 0 is for joining two disks of the same size, so not really useful here.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same laptop and a 4GB and 8 GB partition.
When installing Ubuntu I define the /home, /tmp and /var partitions to be on the second SSD. This way there's still enough free space on the first SSD.

Joining two SSDs into one partition is not possible.
Theoretically a RAID 0 is a joining of 2 disks, but I have no idea if that's possible on that laptop.

Comment: Does anyone know if I can do as @P_M did on install, but after install (I've already installed a few things, and would like to avoid reformatting)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with eeepc. I want to solve it through:

- the 4 GB disk mount on `/boot`
- the 8 GB disk mount on `/root`
- the 8 GB disk in carde reader mount on `/home`

Is this a solution?

But still I would prefer to join the 4 and the 8 GB to one logical volume mounted on `/root`